# Create and login (Auth) with a Google account on my own website

Tags: api, gmail, account

I'm starting a new Internet provider in Belgium. For now, all information concerning this new company is confidential. So I can't give you any information about that.

**What I want to do:**

When my customers register their new subscriptions on my website, I want them to register / log in with their Google / Gmail account.

**We may have 2 cases:**

*1. Customer with existing Google account:*
The new customer already has a Google account and logs into my website using OpenID.

*2. Customer without a Google account:*
The new customer doesn't have a Google account yet, so he or she should create one first befor completing there registration on my website.

In the second case, new customers have no Google account and need to create one before completing their application. I want customers to be able to do that on my website, without leaving my site and navigating to a Google website. This might be done with some APIs.

**The reason for that:**

There are many reasons, but two of the most important are: 1. if a customer ever change their services to another provider, they DON'T lose their mail account, because Google is independent of the ISP. 2. I don't need to provide the mails ervice, webmail application, or the server myself, which would be expensive for the customers.

Please, can someone help me. I've already consulted the Google websmaster and API pages, but I didn't find any solutions.

Note this: I WILL require that my new costumers have email addresses in the gmail.com domain and NOT individual domains like ...@mydomainname.com that are handled by Google.

Thanks in advance for the aid.

Comment: This is a terrible model from a security standpoint.  You're asking your non-Google customers to create a Google account from your own web site, which means you're asking them to *give you their Google credentials* and allow you to create a Google account on their behalf.  *You should never trust a third party with your credentials.*  If those accounts are ever compromised, your website would be the first suspect.  Much better to let them create a Google account directly from google.com (perhaps open a new tab?) and return to your site afterward.

Comment: First:
Offcourse it must be done secured. It's not the meaning to let users create a google account from a form on my website witch communicates Google. But to create a google account from a secured
 Google form within my website. 

Second: 
If I let customers create a googlaccount from a tab, then users LEAVE my website and it may be possible that they DON'T return to my website to finish there order. That way I loose possible customers, and offcourse we don't won't that to happen.

There must be some solution for that, not?